# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{-1}e^{tx}\frac{3}{2}x^{-4}\,dx + \int_1^{\infty}e^{tx}\frac 3 2 x^{-4}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to evaluate the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}e^{tx}\frac{3}{2}x^{-4}\,dx + \int_1^{\infty}e^{tx}\frac 3 2 x^{-4}\,dx.$$

I know this is the exponential integral but I am wondering if it's possible to write this particular case in terms of elementary functions.

The taylor expansion for $e^{tx}$ is $e^{tx} = 1 + tx + \frac{t^2x^2}{2!} + \ldots = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tx)^k}{k!}$, so going down that path I got this far:

\begin{align*}
    \int_{-\infty}^{-1}e^{tx}\frac{3}{2}x^{-4}\,dx + \int_1^{\infty}e^{tx}\frac 3 2 x^{-4}\,dx &= \frac{3}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tx)^k}{k!}x^{-4}\,dx + \frac{3}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tx)^k}{k!} x^{-4}\,dx \\ 
    &= \frac{3}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^4} + \frac{t}{x^3} + \frac{t^2}{2!x^2} + \ldots \right)\,dx \\ &+ \frac{3}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^4} + \frac{t}{x^3} + \frac{t^2}{2!x^2} + \ldots \right)\,dx \\
    &= \frac{3}{2}\left[\frac{-1}{3x^3} + \frac{t}{2x^2} - \frac{t^2}{2!x} + \ldots \right]_{-\infty}^{-1} + \frac{3}{2}\left[\frac{-1}{3x^3} + \frac{t}{2x^2} - \frac{t^2}{2!x} + \ldots \right]_{1}^{\infty} \\
    &= 
\end{align*}

But am now struggling to evaluate the antiderivative at the limits. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure this integral converges? I can see that the second integrand diverges as $x\rightarrow\infty$ for any $t>0$ and first integrand diverges as $x\rightarrow-\infty$ for $t<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm just going to assume that you meant

$$I(t)=\int_1^\infty e^{-tx}x^{-4}dx$$
for $t>0$ because otherwise the integral diverges. As far as I'm concerned, there are no elementary function that describes your integral because it involves error function (that is the antiderivative of Gaussian function) but it can be written as an antiderivative of elementary function.

Observe that

$$I'(t)=\int_{1}^\infty -e^{-tx}x^{-3}dx$$

and on the other hand, integrating by parts,

$$I(t)=\bigg[-\frac{1}{3}e^{-tx}x^{-3}\bigg]_1^\infty-\int_1^\infty\frac{t}{3}e^{-tx}x^{-3}dx=\frac{e^{-t}}{3}+\frac{tI'(t)}{3}.$$

You can then solve for $I(t)$ using method of integrating factor. Here's some reference https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html in case you're not familiar with integrating factor.